# Inconsistent `str(b"")` return values between python versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Python 2.7.13

```
>>> str(b'')
""
>>> bool(str(b''))
False
```

Python 3.6.0

```
>>> str(b'')
"b''"
>>> bool(str(b''))
True
```

My question is two-fold:

- Why does this happen?
- What is the best way to get an empty string from an empty byte string in Python 3.6.0?

Comment: They are both empty. b is just the notation for byte.

Comment: The issue is that `bool(str(b""))` is `True` in 3.6 but `False` in 2.7

Comment: Something is wrong here with your example. In the 3.6 version your string contains the string b single quote single quote.

Comment: Nothng is wrong with the example. Because the string contains that non empty value, `bool()` returns True. Difference is not in `bool` but in Python2 vs Python3 differences relating binary strings treatment.

Comment: Take off the `bool()` and see what `str(b"")` is in the two versions. Hint: it's three characters long in Python 3.

Comment: Decode the bytestring, e.g. with `bool(b''.decode('utf-8'))`